# Advertisements shown when page is viewed in Chromium but not when viewed in Firefox

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, chromium

The title says it all, i keep on seeing advertisements when i open pages in Chromium, those ads are shown in portions of the page (not popups) usually at the bottom and/or the top of the page and do not appear when i open the same page in Firefox.

Those advertisements break the page layout so they clearly are not something coded by the site developer to show AdSense. See screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

I am using GNU/Linux Xubuntu.

One proposed solution i found was to remove the chromium folder inside .config, i tried but it did not help.

I kept on googling but did not find anything recent to be used as a solution so i am posting the question here, hope someone can help, thanks.

**Update-1:** even chrome in my android (s3 neo) is showing a similar behavior since days (ads shown when not expected)

**Update-2:** even firefox (not logged in on google) showed the ad but it disappeared after ctrl+shift+R

**Update-3:** sometimes the ad does not show and an empty area is shown in its place. In those cases an error appears in the console, see screenshot below:

[image]

**Update-4:** the iframe that is trying to show the ad has this url: http://metrika-analytics.com/analytics.js

**Update-5:** another screenshot:

[image]

As you can see there are various "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Those not found resources are like:

1. http://metrika-analytics.com/analytics.js
2. http://img100.xvideos.com/eroteen.info/pics/xnb.gif
3. http://metrika-analytics.com/analytics.js

This looks like a virus and i am on linux.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser` and then `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. **WARNING: This will erase all your bookmarks, history and prefecences**

Comment: This could be caused by one of your add-ons..open `chromium` in incognito mode and check if the ad is there to be sure ...

Comment: @Helio: thats the last resort IMO..you should not suggest something like that out of teh blue..

Comment: And it will neither remove your config, just the chromium package...

Comment: Follow these instructions to create and use a new user profile: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en . Much more convenient than purging and re-installing chrome.

Comment: @Helio thanks for your answer, i tried purging and re-installing but the ad is still there. Fortunately i am synced with google so i did not loose anything.

Comment: @heemayl thanks, i opened the same page (http://askubuntu.com/ in this case) in an incognito window and the ad did not show, strangely because this solution did not work at first when i tried it some days ago. It worked now after purge -> re-install

Comment: One more info to the topic: even google chrome in my android phone (s3 neo) is showing a similar behavior since days (ads shown when not expected)

Comment: Good to hear that..now you should find the culprit add-on and disable/remove it..

Comment: i have no add-ons installed

Comment: Whats the output of  `ls ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions` ? (tag me by adding @ infront of my name `@heemayl`)

Comment: @heemayl

this is the output:

blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo  nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
coobgpohoikkiipiblmjeljniedjpjpf  pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia

Comment: That means you have extensions..Go to "Tools > Extensions" and check for the extensions..

Comment: @heemayl

i have no extensions installed, see screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/omqxqdkasjtuxjp/Screenshot%20-%2004112015%20-%2009%3A30%3A58%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: well then..this might be auto generated responses..does the normal mode still has the ads?

Comment: @heemayl at the moment in normal mode i see the space reserved for the ad but nothing inside, i tried several times in more than one site.

To me it seems the problem is in my google profile because i see unexpected ads even in my android mobile, even after a reset.

Comment: Does page source reveal anything interesting ? Also, you might wanna ask this very same question on http://security.stackexchange.com/ . Those guys know about browser injections a little more than most users here

Comment: Hi @Serg, thanks for the suggestion, i will post the same Q there. The source of the ad reveals divs and other elements that seem typical of AdSense because of the google-x classes. This for example is the parent div's class: adsbygoogle. Also the ad images are served by google  so this clearly seems authentic AdSense.

Comment: I posted the question on http://security.stackexchange.com/ but the post was put on hold as off-topic.
At the same time i keep on seeing unexpected ads. The currently accepted answer by  Penguin Sharpshooter proposed to install AdBlock Plus which i did but sometimes i still have unexpected ads issues.
I would like to make it clear that i expect to see ads on pages, this is pretty normal on the internet but here i am talking of things that break the page layout and appear just on certain circumstances (not in incognito mode e.g.), this looks like a virus and i am on linux!

Answer (score 2):

I use Adblock Plus free extension on my desktop and I never see annoying ads! Via the Acceptable Ads initiative, Adblock Plus allows some small and static ads, and users support websites that rely on advertising but choose to do it in a non-intrusive way. I know this reply probably seems like an ad but honestly, it works. It does exactly what it says it does with no nasty surprises.

Comment: Thanks @Penguin Sharpshooter

Adblock Plus removed the strange ads but it is still a wonder why they appeared in such an unexpected way